Как сделать кнопку с внутренним скруглением?
Как сделать кнопку с внутренним скруглением? Соре за корявость - не художник)


Используйте SVG

Нужна ли прозрачность снаружи или там просто белый фон?

Да, все что снаружи черных контуров - прозрачно, там уже будут элементы

@ΝNL993, спасибо, попробую!
